# IHTMLImgElement to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, winforms, image

I am trying to extract image from c# webbrowser control, and return byte array of the same, i have managed to extract image, buy unable to get byte array of the same.

How do i get IHTMLImgElement to byte[], cannot find good examples on google, please any suggestions ?

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899417/saving-images-from-a-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just downloading the original?

```
string imgSrc = htmlImgElement.src;
WebClient web = new WebClient();
byte[] imageData = web.DownloadData(imgSrc);
```

You may need to convert src to a fullly qualified URL which you can probably get from the webBrowser.Url (?) property.